# SQL Server Express default storage location

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, sql-server-express

The SQL Server Express database is limited to 10GB of storage per database data file. But is that possible to add a new file?

Currently, I am using two databases for my app that stores everything to one default location. What I want to do is store two databases in two different locations.

Comment: **No.** - the 10 GB limit applies to the **database as a whole** - not individual files of the database

Comment: I was reading "https://logicalread.com/sql-server-express-as-a-production-database/#.WN0ojhudBQc" It mentioned that the users can have multiple 10gb databases.

Comment: Yes - you can have **multiple** databases - each up to 10 GB - but you cannot have a **single** database with four or five files with 10GB each - the size of **one whole database** (no matter how many data files you add) is limited to **10 GB**

Comment: Thanks Marc_s. I actually have two databases. I just don't know how I can store one database per file.